# Javascript Interface Object parsing fail

Tags: java, javascript, android, list

I'm having difficulties with parsing `List` from my android java class to my `javascript` through `javascript` interface. Please see my code below;

```
List stl = readAllData();
webview.loadUrl("javascript:showStock("+stl+");");
```

In my javascript;

```
function showStock(data){
    $("#content").html("<div>"+"reached"+"</div>");
}
```

It doesn't print "reached" in my html page. I think there's something wrong with parsing list.

Answer (score 0):

`webview.loadUrl` is used to load data from a URL. if you have certain data like html as a string in your program, use `webview.loadData`

See the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)

Hope it helps.